# Invalid Object Error on Insert after read of same table

Tags: t-sql, object, insert, if-statement

I am trying to insert data into a table based off what is already in the table.  I read the table to get the number of records inserted for a certian month and then insert information based off if it is more or less than ten.  After I read the table it throws an invalid object name when I try to do that insert.  It's not an invalid object as it just read the table.  If this is a permissions error how do I correct it?  My code is below.  Thanks,

Jason

```
declare @email VARCHAR(75),
        @seminarNumber INT,
        @isValidEmail BIT,
        @monthlyTotal INT,
        @statusCode INT
set @email = 'email@domain.com'
set @seminarNumber = '12345'

set @isValidEmail = dbo.RegexMatch('^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(aero|coop|info|museum|name))$',@email)

if @isValidEmail = 1
    begin
        SELECT @monthlyTotal = count(mailid)
        from Email_Tracking
        where emailaddress = @email
        and year(datesent) = year(getdate())
        and month(datesent) = month(getdate())
        if @monthlyTotal > 10
            begin
                set @statusCode = 1
            end
        else
            begin
                set @statusCode = 2
            end
    end
else
    begin
        set @statusCode = 3
    end

if @statusCode = 1
    begin
        insert Email_Tracking ('seminarNumber','email','reasonNotSent')
        values(@seminarNumber,@email,'Maximum  surveys for the month have already been sent')
    end
else if @statusCode = 2
    begin
        insert Email_Tracking ('seminarNumber','email','datesent')
        values(@seminarNumber,@email,getdate())
    end
else if @statusCode = 3
    begin
        insertEmail_Tracking ('seminarNumber','email','reasonNotSent')
        values(@seminarNumber,@email,'Email address missing or invalid')
    end

print @statusCode
```

Comment: What is the exact error messages please? I'd expect "does not exist or do not have permission" or similar. However, it's a vital piece of information...

Comment: I'm going to assume that `insertEmail_Tracking` is not an object (down there after `else if @statusCode = 3`)?

Answer (score 0):

try removing quotes from column names. so for eg:

```
insert Email_Tracking (seminarNumber,email,reasonNotSent)
values(@seminarNumber,@email,'Email address missing or invalid')
```